# Webdriver test with angular loading screen fails in headless mode

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, headless-browser

I have a simple page with several tabs. It uses angular.

On initial page load the elements load, then while the data is loading I have an element on top of everything disabling user activity until the data loads.

Script has a 'wait until visibility of element located' which works when I run it using chromedriver.

When I add "headless" option the test fails because it can't find that element. Is there anything I can do to work on my page and headless or I have to stick it out with using GUI?

code that fails:

```
def loading_appear_disappear(self):
    element = BaseLocators.Locators.OVERLAY_GRID
    wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)      
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(element))   
    wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located(element))
```

if the waits are removed, the code that should get a list of tabs brings back no elements

```
driver.find_elements(*BaseLocators.Locators.TAB_ELEMENTS)
```

Comment: In normal mode what is that element for which you induce `'wait until visibility of element located'`? What is your next step?

Comment: I locate that element by class name. It is an element that is generated after page load completes. In GUI mode, I can't click on anything until that popup goes away.
When I removed the code to to wait until - the test never finds any of my tabs.

Comment: What is your next step after `popup goes away`?

Comment: to get a list of tabs driver.find_elements(*BaseLocators.Locators.TAB_ELEMENTS) - this brings back nothing

Comment: How many elements are returned back? Does it always returns back similar number of elements?

Comment: without headless it returns 5-9 elements always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this with following:
The grid_element is actually the grid that is being blocked by the bar. My guess is that I was trying to 'wait' before the base page finished loading, so it was messing up.

```
try:
        if grid_element.is_displayed and grid_element.is_enabled:
            self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(bar))
            self.wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located(bar))
except WebDriverException:
        #error because 'another element would receive the click' meaning the overlay bar is present
        self.wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located(bar))
```

Answer (score 0):

As we need to wait for the list of `Tab Elements` so,

Instead of :

```
element = BaseLocators.Locators.OVERLAY_GRID
wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(element))   
wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located(element))
```

Try to use :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(*BaseLocators.Locators.TAB_ELEMENTS))
```

### Update:

As you mentioned, `elements are already 'loaded' but inaccessible due to the overlay grid`, so the best clause to use would be `element_to_be_clickable`. In that case you may have to define/declare any one of the `TAB_ELEMENTS` as a `constant` e.g. **`FIRST_TAB_ELEMENT`** and use it in the `wait`

```
wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(*BaseLocators.Locators.FIRST_TAB_ELEMENT))
```

Comment: issue is that elements are already 'loaded' but inaccessible due to the overlay grid. my guess is it 'finds' them but because they are not accessible / interactive, it returns nothing.

Comment: The update fails even in GUI mode. When I initially came up with the original function I tried most of the logical expected conditions, and they did not work. From what I remember the tab becomes 'clickable' after initial DOM loads, but that's also when the overlay grid comes up - so the rest of script fails.